# CSS not loading correctly With React-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to implement the typeahead using Meteor with react syntax. I found this [library](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead) and it look like really good but I'm having some problems with CSS.
My actual code is as the image above
[Real Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4m06.png)
And as we can see in the image above the functionality is there but apparently with wrong CSS

[image]

Any Idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're correctly including the CSS along with your code. I assume you're using a bundler like webpack to create a package for the browser? Can you post your config? My best guess is that you don't have the proper loaders enabled to handle the CSS. As a test, you might also try just including the CSS in your `index.html` file to see if that works.

Comment: Well i only realized now the bootstrap was not loaded .. 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' fix the error.
So noob .. Thank you by the way

Answer (score 1):

Import bootstrap.min.js into your application.
Use the following link:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

**OR**

Import bootstrap.min.css into your application.
Use the following link:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#stylesheets

Adding this to the html worked in my case.